# Deploying a python virtual environment

Tags: python, deployment, pip, virtualenv, wsgi

The thing is pip install can take some time and as a build can inherently be different from the other, some funcionalities may behave different too. My point is:

Is it safe to **copy** the *virtualenv folder* (typically `venv`) from the *staging* environment to the *production* environment?

I know some packages build themselves using `*-dev` packages and header files. But aren't these binaries deployable too? If these packages were the biggest problem, is it possible to install them only in the *production* environment and **copy** the rest of the `venv` folder?

Comment: No, it is never safe to copy virtualenvs around.

Comment: You might want to have a look at docker and deploy containers.

Comment: Virtualenv use hard-coded file paths, it's tricky to change the folder name/path even on the same machine, tho there is a option in venv (`virtualenv --relocatable`) to relocate a folder, i didn't have success with it, and have to change paths manually using search/replace.